# Why can't I get my javascript (Rock, Paper, Scissors game) to show the outputs on my website?

Tags: javascript, html

I can get prompts to pop up on my website but when I do console.log or return in javascript it doesn't print it out on my website.

My website is www.caelanbacon.com

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Caelan Bacon</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var userChoice = prompt ("rock, paper, or scissors?");

while (userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors") {
console.log("Invalid submission.");
userChoice = prompt("Try again?");
}



var computerChoice = Math.random();



if (computerChoice < 0.34 ) {
    console.log = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice < 0.66 ) {
    console.log = "paper";
} else {
    console.log = "scissors";
}


var choice1 = userChoice;
var choice2 = computerChoice;

console.log("You chose " + choice1);
console.log("System: " + choice2);


var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {//start function

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";


    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    } else {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "scissors wins";
        } else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }

}//end function

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);

</script>



<footer>
    &copy; CaelanBacon.com 2016. All rights reserved.
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `console.log` doesn't write to your page. It writes to your console. Hit F12 to open your console. I'd suggest getting well acquainted with it because it's the single most valuable debugging tool you have.

Comment: @MikeC have been using control+shift+j for years, didn´t know there was a shorter shortcut, thanks :)

Comment: @Mike C - I'm confused. I'm on mac (macbook pro osx) and F12 is a sound key, and the function part of it just goes to dashboard… what am I missing? ~ feeling stupid.

Comment: @Bacon Sorry, that's the shortcut for Windows. Try Cmd + Opt + I. [Source](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to add text in your html dynamically. So Add empty paragraph tag with id=p1 in your html. i.e.
`<p id="p1"></p>` 
Now add this script 
`document.getElementById('p1').innerhtml= "Your text"`

Now instead of writing to console, you can add text into your html dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

To put your results into the page you have to inject them into the DOM (Document Object Model of your website) by using JavaScript to get (or create) the element that you want to populate and then add your results inside of that element.

This may help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp. It's part of a larger tutorial on DOM manipulation with JavaScript that can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: I'd probably avoid W3Schools and instead use MDN or Quirksmode, personal preference :) Also see http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Yeah, I know that a lot of folks feel that way.  W3Schools isn't comprehensive but I do find for newbies it has an easy-to-understand interface.  Also, as someone with ADD I find it easier to read w3schools than MDN (although I do use MDN for more comprehensive information) or Quirksmode.  Thanks for the tip on w3fools.com.  I will check it out.